# Async download using checkboxes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, checkbox, download

I have created a WPF C# GUI that should work as a multiple downloader for tools. checkboxes for each app and a download button.

Could anybody help me with a startup for the download code? Very new to C# and while I googled a lot I still haven't found something that works for my case.
The download button should check which of the checkboxes are checked and download the files asynchronously.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ccleaner.IsChecked == true)
        {
            string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string url = "https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download/portable/downloadfile";
            string filename = "ccleaner.zip";
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), desktopPath + "/" + filename);
            }
        }
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Method name expected  on line 10 of mainwindow.xaml

which looks like this:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ccleaner" Content="ccleaner" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="197.883,90.123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="ccleaner"/>
```

Comment: Please post the code that you do have so we can give advice. Have you looked into using Tasks ?

Comment: updated with code. Tasks? what is that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

Comment: So what part of your code doesn't work ? What problems are you having ?

Comment: I'm getting Method name expected error on line 10 of mainwindow.xaml wich looks like this:<CheckBox x:Name="ccleaner" Content="ccleaner" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="197.883,90.123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="ccleaner"/>

Comment: Update your question with your specific issue rather than in a comment

Comment: done...sorry about that

Comment: So it seems the error is actually unrelated to your code in the button click handler ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be related to the checkbox code...

Comment: In your XAML code  Checked="ccleaner", have you got a checked changed method handler called ccleaner ? I believe the error is telling you you have no method called that.

Comment: Truth to be told I don't even know how what I did...what should be there or should it be removed completely?

Comment: Remove the Checked="ccleaner" in your xaml and see if the error goes away - do you need a change handler for when the checkbox check state changes ?

Comment: Couldn't even imagine it was so simple. I just need to download what is checked when the download button is pressed. Will try with more than one checkboxes to see if I get any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As auburg note I had to remove "Checked="ccleaner"" from my xaml code.
Sorry that I can't mark his comment as the solution